# Android: IllegalStateException:Custom actionbar with onClickListener on icons

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener, illegalstateexception

Hi I have custom actionbar with a reset icon , And I have a sliding menu with fragments. when I am in fragmentA and when clicked on reset icon it will reset the values of that particular  fragment in this case fragmentA.

The problem is when I come from fragmentB to fragmentA by clicking the backbutton and when then click actionbar reset its calling the reset method in fragmentB.

Below is how I am calling the onClick event in both the fragments.

**Fragment A**

```
((FragmentChangeActivity) getActivity()).housing_reset.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            resetAllFragmentAFields();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**Frgament B**

```
   ((FragmentChangeActivity) getActivity()).housing_reset.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                resetAllFragmentBFields();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

How to mention the click event of reset icon belongs to a particular fragment.

Getting crash with below log

```
09-02 14:52:43.805: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31011): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment FragemntB not attached to Activity
```

Comment: It is best if you can provide full code of your activity and fragment. For this reset button, it is inside fragment or activity?

Comment: The reset button is in the activity, so custom actionbar is common for fragments inside this activity

Comment: Please provides full code of your activity hari86. I need to take a look on your code structure.

Comment: @AmadYus  http://pastebin.com/Fx2PCPtn